# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. in sql sp execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on this stored procedure and the database is complaining about a syntax error:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_opd_insert_transaction_table]               
--@lkp_Table   NVarchar(500) = ''               
@Table_name  NVARCHAR(500),
@fiscal_year VARCHAR(4)               
--@FieldNameTranspose NVarchar(MAX) = ''                
AS
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       DECLARE @colsUnpivot NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
       SET @colsUnPivot = STUFF(
                          (
                           SELECT ','+code_name
                           FROM opd_lkp_scholar t
                           WHERE fiscal_year = 2015
                            AND 
                            code_name 
                              NOT IN('UNITID', 'Institution', 'City', 'State', 'Zip')
                           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
       PRINT @colsUnPivot;
       SET @query = 'SELECT unitid, institution, city, 
                        state, zip, code_name, lkp_value                 
                  FROM (SELECT '+@colsUnpivot+'             
                  FROM '+@Table_name+') AS cp                  
                  UNPIVOT (lkp_value for code_name  IN ('+
                   @colsUnPivot+')) AS up';
       PRINT @Query;
       EXEC (@query);
    END;
```

When I execute this stored procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Can you please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: check the messages tab to see what is the query the PRINT statement prints.

Comment: Anyway I found the answer. Thnaks a lot. Its one of the column called AS so I should put that in bracket [AS].

Comment: you can USE QUOTENAME for that

Comment: set @colsUnPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ','             
                  + QUOTENAME(code_name)                 
                from opd_lkp_scholar t             
                Where fiscal_year = 2015          
                AND code_name NOT IN                                   ('UNITID','Institution','City','State','Zip')               
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE                   
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                    
    ,1,1,'')

Comment: Thanks Perfect man. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What database? It should be in question and tags.